# Using C# classes/structs in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, clr

Is there any way that I can declare instances of a .Net class or struct in a SQL Server stored procedure and/or use them as parameters in a function?

I have a .Net method that takes two instances of my `UnitOfMeasure` class and converts a value from one unit to the other.

My .Net class looks something like this the following. I've omitted a lot of code for the sake of brevity...

```
public class UnitOfMeasure
{
    public static UnitOfMeasure Gram {get;} = new UnitOfMeasure("gram","g",UnitType.Mass, 0.001, 0);
    public static UnitOfMeasure Kilogram {get;} = new UnitOfMeasure("kilogram","kg",UnitType.Mass,1,0);
    ...
    public static IEnumerable<UnitOfMeasure> NamedUnits {get;} = 
       new List<UnitOfMeasure>(){Gram, Kilogram, ...};

    public string Name {get; private set;}
    public string Symbol {get; private set; }
    public UnitType {get; private set;}
    public double StandardUnits {get; private set}
    public double StandardOffset {get; private set}

    public UnitOfMeasure(string name, string symbol, UnitType type, double standardUnits, double standardOffset)
    {
       ...
    }

    public static double? Convert(UnitOfMeasure fromUnit, UnitOfMeasure toUnit, double? value)
    {
       double? standardvalue = (value * fromUnit.StandardUnits) + fromUnit.StandardOffset;
       double ret = (standardvalue - toUnit.StandardOffset)/ toUnit.StandardUnits;
       return ret;
    }

    public static double Convert(string fromUnit, string toUnit, double? value)
    {
       var unit1 = NamedUnits.Single(unit => unit.Name == fromUnit);
       var unit2 = NamedUnits.Single(unit => unit.Name == toUnit);
       return Convert(unit1, unit2, value);
    }
}
```

I've already been able to map my convert (by name) method to a UDF in my database, but it only works for when convert from/to units that are in my "Named Units" collection.

```
 udf_ConvertUnits('gram', 'kilogram', 200); //returns 0.2
```

I would like to also be able to define custom units within the SQL itself and convert between them...

```
 declare @USD = CreateUnit('US Dollar', 'USD', 'Currency', 100, 0);
 declare @EUR = CreateUnit('Euro', 'EUR', 'Currency', 88.9, 0);

 udf_ConvertCustomUnits(@USD, @EUR, 200); // returns 177.8
```

Comment: Probably you can use sql server custom type, and convert it to your .net type ?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't know about any C# types, because it is not C#. As far as I know SQL Server doesn't have a type system equivalent to what C# has, so this can't be done exactly like you want it to be done.